# Nodejs efficient calculation through multidimensional array

Tags: node.js, multidimensional-array, computation

suppose that we have a multidimensional array like this:

[ [{ a: 0} , {a: 1} , {a: 2}], [{ b: 0} , {b: 1}], [{ c: 0} , {c: 1} , {c: 2},  {c: 3}]]

what i want to obtain are all combinations from

- a0,b0,c0
- a0,b0,c1
- a0,b0,c2
- a0,b0,c3
- a0,b1,c0
- a0,b1,c1
- a0,b1,c2
- a0,b1,c3

     ...
- a2,b1,c3

The problem is that in my real-life exercise i've got multidimensional array NxM where n=20 and m is max 5.  My heap is sweating and computational time is extremely long.

Comment: https://www.kcats.org/csci/464/doc/knuth/fascicles/fasc3a.pdf

Comment: There isn't really a question here.  Post your code of what you are doing at the moment to see if it can be improved upon